# Primefaces Data Table Total Records with Paginator

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, pagination

I am using Primefaces 5.1 and displaying total records in index.xhtml and it is perfectly working fine if I am NOT using paginator.

```
<h:body>
    <div id="message">
    <p>There are #{uBean.dataTable.rowCount} matching records.</p>
    </div>
    <h:form>
       <p:tabView widgetVar="tabWidget" id="rTab" cellpadding="0px" cache="true">
```

When I start using paginator for my primefaces table, then I see the records are showing from the previous rendered count. Is there any way to refresh to display after load the page or delay to display this div or any other simple solutions.
           ----

Comment: The reason it is one behind if displayed **before** the datatable can be read here http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/moveComponent I'll try to find a dupe or create an answer tomorrow

Comment: I tried ajax status  '<div id="message">
  <p:ajaxStatus style="display:block;  ">
   <f:facet name="default">
    <h:outputText
     value="There are #{uBean.dataTable.rowCount} records loaded." />
   </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="start">
    <h:outputText
     value="Please wait #{loginBean.uname}, Querying database" />
   </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="complete">
    <h:outputText value="Please wait #{loginBean.uname}, Loading table" />
   </f:facet>
  </p:ajaxStatus>
 </div>' end up with same result.

Comment: **Where** did you put this. It, by default, only works when you put it AFTER the datatable, unless you use the PF 'fix'

Comment: In my xhtml where displaying data table. The row count always loading the previous count. Is there anyway I can delay to display ajax status message?

Comment: Duhhh… ;-) displaying the count outside the datatable by default only works when put AFTER the datatable.

Comment: Ok. May by I mislead because it is worked without paginatior on the same place. Let me try to move the lines after the data table in xhtml and I will update here.

Comment: If you don't use the paginator AND no  paging in one way or another, you use the data retrieved in your bean. That that can be displayed is not strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces loads/processes data for the datatable in the RenderResponse phase. This is very late in the jsf phases and that means that e.g. the rowcount or pagenumber is only available for components that are rendered after the datatable and that in turn means only for components that in the xhtml come after the datatable.

If you want to display things in a growl, this is usually not a problem since it displays at a 'absolute' location and you can put it after the datatable. But rendering it in a different kind of component and displaying it inline is not possible without a workaround.

For a workaround, you have two options

1. Put your component after the datatable and in an oncomplete of an ajax call, use jquery dom manipulation to move it in front of the datatable
2. Use the [OmniFaces moveComponent](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/moveComponent) to achieve the same result

Comment: I added following script after my data table and as per Kukeltje workaround and working fine.  <script>$('#message').prepend('There are #{uBean.dataTable.rowCount} matching records');
</script>